# Report works in Crystal Reports, but not through our EHR

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, odbc

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvlRQ.png)

When trying to run this report out of our EHR, we are getting this error code. It seems to not find the table, but I know it is there and verified everything through Crystal Reports and DBeaver. We have the report setup as a subreport for just the list of medications, but users cannot run it from the EHR. I double checked their ODBC drivers, and they are able to run other reports. Just not this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on that table.

If that was not the issue, open the report in Crystal Designer and use the menu options of ***Database***, ***Verify Database...*** to ensure the report is in sync with the database.

Comment: Checked permissions on the table and everything is good on my end. My staff was able to fix a few things and it works for others now, but not me. This is progress in my book. I also verified the database and it is syncing with the database. We added data in the EHR to test, and it did pull through. Thank you for the feedback though. I will keep digging and see if I can come up with something and hopefully post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ask one of the other users to log in to your machine and test.

If they can still connect, the problem is with your permissions.

If they can't, the problem is with connectivity setup on your machine (database driver, ODBC DSN, etc.)